# AngularJS and OnsenUI: Dynamic Loading of Controllers

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I am working on a mobility app which uses AngularJS and OnsenUI. For navigating from a page to the other I have used the ons-navigator "pushPage".
There is a requirement where in I do not want to load all the controllers in index.html. I would want to load it on demand. I could load a normal JavaScript file as when required using the below code snippet.

```
var fileref = document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

But when I try to do the same thing for a controller(AngularJS) file, the page fails to load. Let me know a suitable fix for it since I cannot use $routeProvider.